# Move unambiguously to the next position with changing rows

Tags: cursor-movement

By pressing `l` you can move to the next position in a line. Unless you are at the end of the current line, in which case you won't move at all.

Is there some simple way to automatically move to the next line, if you reached the end of the current line?

Note: I don't want to use this in my normal workflow, but rather this would make my script much more feasible, because I wouldn't always have to concern myself with that possibility.

EDIT: Actually `<space>` does that, but how are you supposed to execute space with the `normal!` command? It will just ignore it and complain that there are no arguments...

Comment: `normal! 1 `(1 followed by space?)

Comment: Yes! That's it. It's always simpler than you think, if you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `<space>` as the first command with `normal` is discussed in the help. From [`:h :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal):

```
{commands} cannot start with a space.  Put a count of
1 (one) before it, "1 " is one space.
```

So: `:normal! 1` .